# How can I include libcurl correctly using GCC (on Windows)?

Tags: c, gcc, curl

I'm getting a linker error whenever I #include  in my program. I have downloaded libcurl from haxx.se, compiled libcurl.dll, and added -Icurl to my GCC options when compiling (as well as tried adding a direct path using -L to the dll). However, I still get the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
```

My compile command includes this:

```
-Icurl -L"F:/GCCnew/lib/libcurl.dll"
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's something simple but I can't work it out and searching hasn't given me a solution that doesn't use something like Code::blocks.

Comment: hello there, running into similar issues. did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Clyme sorry, it's been quite a long time since I posted this and I do not remember!

Answer (score 1):

> My compile command includes this:
>
> -Icurl -L"F:/GCCnew/lib/libcurl.dll"

If you use mingw gcc, then:

- First, `-L` must have a folder name, not a library name.
- Second, there must be '-l' option. For example -lcurl.
- Third, -Icurl is irrelevant to your linker error

So the command to build might look like:

```
gcc your-file.c -o executable_name -L"F:/GCCnew/lib" -lcurl
```

Useful links:

- http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL (Building a client executable)
- http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use
- http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LibraryPathHOWTO

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I've also tried placing libcurl.a, libcurldll.a, and libcurl.dll in the same directory as the file I'm compiling and using -L. -lcurl as options, but that also didn't work.